Please help me solve this polynomial equation. I would like to know how many integer solution it has?
the equation
$$8x^3 − xy − x − 5y − 13 = 0$$
It has integer solutions, that is, solutions of the form $(x, y)$, where $x$ and $y$ are integers.
(a) Verify that $(1, -1)$ is an integer solution of the equation.
(b) How many integer solutions does the equation have?
(c) Find all integer solutions of the equation where $x$ is a prime number.
(d) Find all integer solutions of the equation where $x$ and $y$ are negative integers.

$1.$ Mathjax Tutorial                           $2.$  How to ask a Good Question Here

What have you tried? In which of a), b), c), d) did you start having difficulties? Are there any examples in your notes or your textbook of such a problem?

Right from question b) I started having problems solving it, I couldn't even start, I have no idea.

i tried to solve with Diophantine Equation but i think that isn't the right track.
